Ansible-map fuction
  employees:
    sarav:
      city: Coimbatore
      email: sarav@gritfy.com
      mobile: '985643210'

  tasks:
    - name: gathering_complete_data
      ansible.builtin.debug:
         msg={{ ['sarav'] | map('extract', employees , 'email' ) }}

output:
ok: [CS1] => {
    "msg": [
        "sarav@gritfy.com"
    ]
}

The above script is successfully working. When I made the data structure:
  employees:
    sarav:
    - city: Coimbatore
      email: sarav@gritfy.com
      mobile: '985643210'

Using the Ansible map filter, I cannot gather the information(sarav's email ID).
Could anyone please share the code for fetching sarav's email ID?

Please take a moment to fix the formatting in this question; there is help available in the editor.

You don't need to map the filter extract. You can directly address the attribute
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ employees.sarav.email }}"

gives
  msg: sarav@gritfy.com

In the second case, you can map the attribute
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ employees.sarav | map(attribute='email') }}"

gives
  msg:
  - sarav@gritfy.com



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    employees:
      sarav:
        city: Coimbatore
        email: sarav@gritfy.com
        mobile: '985643210'

    employee2:
      sarav:
      - city: Coimbatore
        email: sarav@gritfy.com
        mobile: '985643210'

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ employees.sarav.email }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ employee2.sarav | map(attribute='email') }}"


